# Fade Effect on ion-slide-box in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have used ion-slide-box to show slides on home page of application,
But i can't found the fade effect to ionic slide box.

I have used the following code to show slides , please suggest me how to add fade effect ion-slide-box. (Ionic Version - 1.7.15)

```
        <ion-view>
           <ion-content>
                 <div class="top-icons">
                    <div class="row paddings">
                     Some content are here
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="slider-container">
                    <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="true" auto-play="true" slide-interval="5000">
                       <ion-slide class="slider-res">
                          <img src="image/slider/img1.jpg" />
                          <div class="slider-text">Text Content</div>
                       </ion-slide>
                       <ion-slide  class="slider-res">
                          <img src="image/slider/img2.jpg" />
                          <div class="slider-text">Text Content</div>
                       </ion-slide>
                       <ion-slide  class="slider-res">
                          <img src="image/slider/img3.jpg" />
                          <div class="slider-text">Text Content</div>
                       </ion-slide>
                       <ion-slide  class="slider-res">
                          <img src="image/slider/img4.png" />
                          <div class="slider-text">Text Content</div>
                       </ion-slide>
                    </ion-slide-box>
                </div>
                <div>
                Other Content are here
                </div>
        </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.